# Using the chain rule with multivariable functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose the the radius of a right circular cone increases as $r(t) = t^a$ and height decreases as $h(t) = t^{-b}$, where a and b are positive constants. What is the relationship between a and b such that the volume of the cone remains constant. Remainder, the volume of a cone is given as $V=(\pi/3)r^2h$.

Comment: Has the curriculum not covered partial differentiation?

Comment: It has, but I ended up with the messy equation $dz/dt=(2\pi h/3)*at^{a-1} + (\pi r^2/3)*-bt^{-b-1}$ and I wasnt sure where to go from there.

Comment: You have $\partial V / \partial (r^2)$ incorrect. Once that's fixed, you have $dz/dt = 0$, so multiply by $t$ on both sides, then you can substitute $r = t^a$ and $h = t^{-b}$ back in. See where that gets you.